# Safari Mobile - Still getting prompted to block popup despite setting block popup to false

Tags: javascript, angular

In my safari browser on iPhone 11, I have "block popups" turned off.
However with the following line of angular code, I am still getting prompted a pop-up message:

`This site is attempting to open pop-up window`

Here is the line of code I am using on click:

`this.service1.url(this.Method1()).subscribe( response => { window.open('www.google.com', '_blank');} );`

What am I missing, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be occurring if the opening of the new tab isn't the result of a user initiated event, or if there's an `async` delay after the user event

Details from  [JavaScript.info](https://javascript.info/popup-windows)

```
// Most browsers block popups if they are called outside of user-triggered event handlers like onclick.

// For example:

// popup blocked
window.open('https://javascript.info');

// popup allowed
button.onclick = () => {
  window.open('https://javascript.info');
};
// This way users are somewhat protected from unwanted popups, but the functionality is not disabled totally.
```